# TextBox's Text Property returns null when using CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I managed to create a `Command`, like so:

*Code-behind*

```
public static RoutedCommand GetValueCommand = new RoutedCommand();
private void ExecutedGetValueCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Custom Command Executed");
    Button b = (sender) as Button;
    MessageBox.Show(b.CommandParameter.ToString());
}
private void CanExecuteGetValueCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

*XAML*

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
                    Executed="ExecutedGetValueCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteGetValueCommand" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductDescription}"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtExchangeQuantity"
                                     Tag="{Binding ProductBarcode}"/>
                            <Button Content="Add"
                                    Tag="{Binding ProductBarcode}"
                                    Command="{x:Static local:ReturnsUserControl.GetValueCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=txtExchangeQuantity}"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When I clicked the button, `CommandParameter` always return null, even when I put something in the text box, and I'm sure that the command is working because `Custom Command Executed` shows.

What I want to achieve here is to get the value of the `TextBox` that has the same `Tag` value as the `Button`'s `Tag` *(same barcode)*, because there will be multiple instances of both the `TextBox` and the `Button`, and the `Tag` is the only one that can pair them.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the output window? Like Error:40 or 41?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'm not really sure, let me check.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I can only see `System.NullReferenceException` plus the stack trace

Comment: Could you put that info into your question? We need more info about what is going on with your code. And please paste the full error code and description i.e. where it occurs.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I added my objective

Comment: Have you tried checking the `Parameter` on your `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`? Instead of checking the senders `CommandParameter`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX It worked, but why does `CommandParameter` returns null but `e.Parameter` is not when the data also comes from `CommandParameter`?

Comment: I wish I could tell you. But it wouldn't be the first time Binding is not picked up from code behind. In XAML it works nicely.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I see, well at least worked. If you want, you could add it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @XAMlMAX One more thing, how would I get the `Tag` of the `Button` or the `TextBox`? Since I can only bind one property in the `CommandParameter`. `b.Tag.ToString()` returns null to me

Comment: That's a separate question. Post a new one and let us know here with a link to the new question. I think I know what you a re asking and I might be able to help but I need more info or coffee :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX Sure sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we spoke in the comments, you should be looking for `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.Parameter` instead of checking the `sender` in your event handler.